# Windows.Forms DragLeave Event Firing unexpectedly

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling, drag-and-drop

A custom UserControl `ChartControlShelf` contains a `TableLayoutPanel` with 3 child controls, all type `Panel`. Children have no EventHandlers.

`ShelfContainer` adds all EventHandlers for UserControl `ChartControlShelf`:

```cs
ChartControlShelf chartControlShelf = new ChartControlShelf();
chartControlShelf.DragOver+=new DragEventHandler(chartControlShelf_DragOver);
chartControlShelf.DragLeave+=new EventHandler(chartControlShelf_DragLeave);
```

....

```cs
private void chartControlShelf_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {

        ChartControlShelf chartControlShelf = (ChartControlShelf)sender;

        if (chartControlShelf.panelControlShelf.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y < chartControlShelf.tlpChartControlShelf.Size.Height / 2) {
            chartControlShelf.panelInsertTop.BackColor = CustomColorsColors.DragEnter;
            chartControlShelf.panelInsertBottom.BackColor = CustomColorsColors.DragLeave;
        }
        else {
            chartControlShelf.panelInsertBottom.BackColor = CustomColorsColors.DragEnter;
            chartControlShelf.panelInsertTop.BackColor = CustomColorsColors.DragLeave;
        }
   }

    private void chartControlShelf_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ChartControlShelf chartControlShelf = (ChartControlShelf)sender;
        chartControlShelf.panelInsertTop.BackColor = CustomColorsColors.DragLeave;
        chartControlShelf.panelInsertBottom.BackColor = CustomColorsColors.DragLeave;

    }
```

Why is the *chartControlShelf_DragLeave* firing **before** my mouse leaves the `ChartControlShelf` UserControl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mouse cursor "belongs" to the control directly visible below the pointer. As strange as it sounds, When the cursor "enters" one of the controls inside ChartControlShelf, it also "leaves" the ChartControlSelf.

Comment: I had a similar issue, your answer pointed me in the right direction. The solution for me was to set property AllowDrop to false on all of the controls, except the main one.